# stop Wordpress removing shortcode from content

Tags: shortcode, editor

I've found that Wordpress is removing `&nbsp;` from my content, so from [this page](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/prevent-nbsp-characters-from-getting-removed-by-the-visual-editor), I added the following to my `functions.php`:

```
function nbsp_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $content = '&nbsp';
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode( 'nbsp', 'nbsp_shortcode' );
```

I refreshed my Wordpress admin, and after I add `[nbsp]` in my content code, and save, the shortcode is removed from my content code.

I've searched for *stop wordpress remove shortcode from content* and not found an answer to this problem.

How do I stop wordpress removing shortcode from content?

***Update***: From Pieter's advice, I found in the parent theme's `/functions/theme-functions.php`:

```
function strip_shortcode($code, $content) {
    global $shortcode_tags;
    $stack = $shortcode_tags;
    $shortcode_tags = array($code => 1);
    $content = strip_shortcodes($content);
    $shortcode_tags = $stack;
    return $content;
}
```

This function is only referenced once in the parent/child themes:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'strip_html_from_the_content' ) ) {
    function strip_html_from_the_content($content, $tags = '') {
        global $post; 
        $post_format = get_post_format( $post->ID );
        $post_format = ( false === $post_format ) ? 'standard' : $post_format;  
        if ( is_home() && $post_format == 'gallery' ) {
            $content = strip_shortcode('gallery', $content);        
        }
        return $content;
    }
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'strip_html_from_the_content'); 
}
```

I'm not sure what needs to happen here. `strip_shortcode` is only being called `if ( is_home() && $post_format == 'gallery' )`, but the issue occurs on a simple page.

I've added:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'strip_html_from_the_content' );
```

to the child theme's `functions.php` but the issue remains.

***Update2***: I've tried adding the following to the child theme's `functions.php`:

```
function ors_stop_strip_html_from_the_content() {
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'strip_html_from_the_content' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'ors_stop_strip_html_from_the_content' );
```

but the issue remains.

Comment: WordPress does not remove shortcodes, something (*filter*) in a theme or plugin is doing this. You need to do basic debugging yourself to find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

After theme's [setup](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_setup_theme/)

Ask for filter's [removal](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter)

All in child's [getup](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Using_functions.php)

--

Brain is getting hot

Bold assuming approval

Best Haiku it's not

Comment: Forgive this [Friday answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36918/always-friday-in-iceland) ;-) It looks like your theme is not prefixing it's function names, that can lead to possible name collisions. The child theme's functions.php file loads before the parent theme's functions.php file, so the idea was to remove the filter after it's added by the parent theme, via relevant hooks @Steve

Comment: Another option would be to override the `strip_html_from_the_content()` function to an identity map (`f(x) = x`), in your child theme's `functions.php`. @Steve

Comment: Thanks @birgire. I did not mind the `Friday answer`. I am not a developer, so I am unsure hot to map the function to an identity map (although I understand the concept), and searching for _override the function to an identity map (f(x) = x) in your child theme's functions.php_ brings no results.

Comment: Since there's a `function_exists()` check for that function within the parent theme's `functions.php`, you can redefine it to your needs, in the child theme's `functions.php` file. Example: `function strip_html_from_the_content( $content ) { return $content; }`.  Also note how the add_filter is added within the if-condition in your code snippet, so it will not be activated if you define the function yourself (unless you add it yourself) That's a rather strange setup in the parent theme, imho @Steve

Comment: Thanks @birgire. I added `strip_html_from_the_content( $content ) { return $content; }` inside the child theme's `functions.php` and the issue remains...

Comment: The problem is that `strip_shortcode` is only being called if `( is_home() && $post_format == 'gallery' )`, but the issue occurs on a simple page.

Comment: If the problem is not on the home page, then I guess there's something else within your theme/plugins that's causing this. Also make sure you're using the_content() and not e.g. the_excerpt() when you display the page content. @Steve

Comment: Yep, `the_content()` is being used, and you're right, it is a plugin causing the issue - deactivating all plugins stops the shortcode being stripped. I'll isolate the plugin. Thanks.

Comment: Weird. I enabled plugins one by one, and the symptom has not reappeared.

Comment: Even weirder @birgire: I've added some shortcode from [Accordian Shortcodes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/accordion-shortcodes/), and these shortcodes are removed with the same plugins activated when the shortcode in question is not removed.

Comment: Good to hear you have isolated this to the installed plugins, but it's hard for me say what's causing this, could be so many things. So this is a rather localized problem specific to your plugin setup. Best of luck debugging the 3rd party plugins. @Steve